# redirect old domain example.com/subpages to respective newdomain.com/subpages using Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress, nginx-config, nginx-location

Let's say I have a old domain "example.com" and a new one "newdomain.com"

the old and new domains have the same sub location pages for example
example.com/test1/ = newdomain.com/test1/
example.com/test2/ = newdomain.com/test2/
and so on

I need an Nginx rule to do redirects all subpages from the old domain to the new domain respective subpages

Comment: Do you have two Nginx `server` blocks, one for each site? Just use `return 301 https://newdomain.com$request_uri;`

Comment: Yes If the domain is the same but the different is subdomain like the below
beta.domain.com/test1 to domain.com/test1 and beta.domain.com/test2 to beta.domain.com/test2 and so on